# Writing a complex dired function to open xterm and execute a command on all current marked files in dired

Tags: dired, term

I'm trying to write a complex (to me) dired function, where I want to open a xterm window which will launch an application (fbot) with many arguments and input all marked dired files into that statement. This is based on that if I run in dired `&` followed by this

```
xterm -e filebot -script fn:amc  /home/zeltak/mounts/lraid/raid/ztmp/amc  --output "/home/zeltak/mounts/lraid/raid/ztmp/" --def @/home/zeltak/.config/filebot/Q.txt --action move --conflict skip -non-strict  --mode interactive *
```

It works exactly as expected. So I tried fiddling with a function based on that and this is where I am in now which doesn't seem to work:

```
(defun z/dired-media-filebot-xterm ()
"filebot amc interactive"
(interactive)
(start-process "xterm -e filebot -script fn:amc  /home/zeltak/mounts/lraid/raid/ztmp/amc  --output "/home/zeltak/mounts/lraid/raid/ztmp/" --def @/home/zeltak/.config/filebot/Q.txt --action move --conflict skip -non-strict  --mode interactive * &" nil "filebot" file)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use xterm? Dired already has a function to run shell commands on a list of files: `dired-do-shell-command`, that seems like an easier place to start. If for some reason you do need to run your command through xterm, it might be simpler to wrap it up in a shell script, then call that shell script via `dired-do-shell-command`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e filebot <argument list> @1
```

## Update

I don't have filebot available to test with, but this works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e nano $1
```

If that works for you, your problem must be with filebot. If it doesn't work for you, I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: thx @Tyler. well the filebot command is interactive and will present menus via a ncurses interface. will emacs be able to deal with that?

Comment: also @tyler, the above simple bash script launches a xterm window which closes after a second when i launch it from dired (& tst.sh)

Comment: No, you can't use ncurses within Emacs (or maybe via term-mode, but I find that a pain). You should be able to call xterm from a script as I describe though.

Comment: hmm so i cant seem to get it to work for me. this is current script: https://paste.xinu.at/lHH7x/. yet it just flashes a xterm window for 1 sec? i use it by marking a dired file, pressing & then paste test.sh *

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: thx its working now